# Silverstripe Requirements::css() does not include css

Tags: php, silverstripe

I try to include custom css file for a certain page. I use `Requirements::css()` method in the PageController `init()`, but I also tried the template tag: `<% require css(mytheme/css/aa.css) %>`. The result is, there's no link to the file in generated page. There are no errors reported, just no effect. The `init()` method gets called, I can fire log from inside of it.

```
class AaPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function init () {
        parent::init();
        Requirements::css("mytheme/css/aa.css");
    }

}
```

I'm walking in circles now, could anyone with more SS experience suggest a way to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running a `flush` or clearing the cache manually?

Comment: Yes. I did run ?flush=1. I'm using SS v3.4 if that matters. Also I think, flush helps with template changes, do I need it after modifying php files as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shame that the new API docs don't show the explanation of the method parameters any more, hopefully it's fixed soon.

If you [look at the code](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3/view/Requirements.php#L167) (which is easy with a proper IDE, cause you can jump to the method your're calling) you'll see :

```
/**
 * Register the given stylesheet into the list of requirements.
 *
 * @param string $file  The CSS file to load, relative to site root
 * @param string $media Comma-separated list of media types to use in the link tag
 *                      (e.g. 'screen,projector')
 */
public static function css($file, $media = null) {
    self::backend()->css($file, $media);
}
```

> The CSS file to load, **relative to site root**

As your theme is not at the site root, you need something like this:

```
Requirements::css("themes/mytheme/css/aa.css");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `Requirements::themedCSS`. So to include `aa.css`, you could do:

```
Requirements::themedCSS('aa');
```

And in your template:

```
<% require themedCSS("aa") %>
```

This way it'll automatically search the template folder(s) for the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `head` area in your template file? You'll need to make sure that your `.ss` file has the bear minimum before Silverstipe will add your requirements css file to it. A basic html skeleton like the one below needs to be present.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe so. I'm using a page.ss main layout template, which has a `$Layout` placeholder for the subpage template (which in turn renders the proper content). The main template file has all the html stuff. Maybe I should strip it to a bare minimum and see what happens.